# Очень медленно едет машина, при этом колеса вращаются очень быстро

Tags: c#, unity3d

Так и не удалось разобраться.
Есть такой код:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Car : MonoBehaviour {

    private float m_horizontalInput;
    private float m_verticalInput;
    private float m_steeringAngle;

    public WheelCollider frontDriverW, frontPassengerW;

    public WheelCollider rearDriverW, rearPassengerW;


    public Transform frontDriverT, frontPassengerT;
    public Transform rearDriverT, rearPassengerT;
    public float maxSteerAngle = 30;
    public float motorForce = 50;

    public void GetInput() {
        ++m_horizontalInput;
        ++m_verticalInput;
    }

    private void Steer() {
        m_steeringAngle = maxSteerAngle * m_horizontalInput;
        frontDriverW.steerAngle = m_steeringAngle;
        frontPassengerW.steerAngle = m_steeringAngle;
    }

    private void Accelerate() {
        frontDriverW.motorTorque = m_verticalInput * motorForce;
        frontPassengerW.motorTorque = m_verticalInput * motorForce;
    }

    private void UpdateWheelPoses() {
        UpdateWheelPose(frontDriverW, frontDriverT);
        UpdateWheelPose(frontPassengerW, frontPassengerT);
        UpdateWheelPose(rearDriverW, rearDriverT);
        UpdateWheelPose(rearPassengerW, rearPassengerT);
    }

    private void UpdateWheelPose(WheelCollider _collider, Transform _transform) {
        Vector3 _pos = _transform.position;
        Quaternion _quat = _transform.rotation;
        _collider.GetWorldPose(out _pos, out _quat);
        _transform.position = _pos;
        _transform.rotation = _quat;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        GetInput();
        Steer();
        Accelerate();
        UpdateWheelPoses();
    }
}
```

В чем может быть проблема, что машина едет очень медленно, даже когда я делают нереальные значения, она начинает ехать чуть быстрее, но после значения `5000+` никаких изменений не происходит.

Сам скрипт висит на главном объекте `Car`, в нее вложены 4 колеса, 2 передних ведущий и 2 задних.
Также скопированы еще 4 для `WheelCollider`, все работает, колеса вращаются очень быстро или очень медленно, а сама машина как черепаха двигается, никак не могу понять в чем проблема и как поправить.

На объекте `Car` также висит `RigidBody` = `useGravity = true` и `BoxCollider`.
Если что-то не хватает к вопросу, говорите, я просто не знаю, что еще надо, это полный код.

Кто-то знает, в чем беда?

Причем я заметил, что если объект увеличиваем через `scale`, то так собственно и происходит.

Что вообще за дела творятся, почему при увеличении радиуса колеса он начинает тоже крутиться медленно, что вообще происходит, что нужно делать и какие значения менять, ничего не понимаю вообще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, проблема в том, что сама модель была огромная, а я уменьшил ее в юнити через скейл, что делать не нужно было, уменьшил через 3д редактор, все заработало как нужно.